# Do not load the css file for a plugin from the header

Tags: wp-register-style

I'm newbie to PHP.
I need to remove a css file from home of my site
This is the html code to remove

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='__EPYT__style-css'  href='https://www.*****/wp-content/plugins/youtube-embed-plus/styles/ytprefs.min.css?ver=13.4.1.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

I've insert in my functions.php in the child theme this code:

```
function load_scriptsyt() {
        wp_register_style( 'youtube-embed-plus2', plugins_url('youtube-embed-plus/styles/ytprefs.min.css'));
        wp_dequeue_style( 'youtube-embed-plus2');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scriptsyt', 100);
```

But doesn't works ,
any advices?

Comment: Well if you want to remove it, you shouldn't use `wp_register_style()`, you only want `wp_dequeue_style()`. But what you want to do is find the proper 'handle'. It's likely not `youtube-embed-plus2`. It's possibly `__EPYT__style`, but you'll need to check the plugin's source code to be sure. If you're not sure how to do that you'll need to ask the developer.

Comment: Additionally, you want to make sure that your dequeueing runs after the plugin's enqueueing, otherwise you'll attempt to remove something that isn't there and then the plugin will still add it in afterwards.